# Вывести календарь на год

Tags: java, calendar

Пытаюсь придумать, как реализовать вывод календаря в консоль. Совсем не могу сообразить, как правильно вывести дату для каждого дня недели и сделать перенос на следующий месяц. Явно представляю, что нужно делать, но не знаю, как это сделать на Java. Получаем день недели, выводим несколько пробелов по его индексу, потом выводим числа. В общем как это можно реализовать?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("Пн\tВт\tСр\tЧт\tПт\tСб\tВс");
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                System.out.print(gregorianCalendar.get(gregorianCalendar.DATE) + "\t");
                gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю это то что вам нужно.

```
/************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac Calendar.java
 *  Execution:    java Calendar M Y
 *
 *  This program takes the month M and year Y and prints a
 *  calendar for that month.
 * 
 *  % java Calendar 7 2005
 *   July 2005
 *   S  M  T  W Th  F  S
 *                  1  2 
 *   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
 *  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
 *  17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
 *  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
 *  31 
 *  
 ************************************************************************/

public class Calendar { 

   /***************************************************************************
    *  Given the month (M), day (D), and year (Y), return which day
    *  of the week it falls on according to the Gregorian calendar.
    *  For M use 1 for January, 2 for February, and so forth. Outputs
    *  0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so forth.
    ***************************************************************************/
    public static int day(int M, int D, int Y) {
        int y = Y - (14 - M) / 12;
        int x = y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400;
        int m = M + 12 * ((14 - M) / 12) - 2;
        int d = (D + x + (31*m)/12) % 7;
        return d;
    }

    // return true if the given year is a leap year
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if  ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) return true;
        if  (year % 400 == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    // month (Jan = 1, Dec = 12)
        int Y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    // year

        // months[i] = name of month i
        String[] months = {
            "",                               // leave empty so that months[1] = "January"
            "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"
        };

        // days[i] = number of days in month i
        int[] days = {
            0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
        };

        // check for leap year
        if (M == 2 && isLeapYear(Y)) days[M] = 29;


        // print calendar header
        StdOut.println("   " + months[M] + " " + Y);
        StdOut.println(" S  M Tu  W Th  F  S");

        // starting day
        int d = day(M, 1, Y);

        // print the calendar
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
            StdOut.print("   ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= days[M]; i++) {
            StdOut.printf("%2d ", i);
            if (((i + d) % 7 == 0) || (i == days[M])) StdOut.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] months = {"ЯНВАРЬ", "ФЕВРАЛЬ", "МАРТ", "АПРЕЛЬ", "МАЙ", "ИЮНЬ", "ИЮЛЬ", "АВГУСТ", "СЕНТЯБРЬ", "ОКТЯБРЬ", "НОЯБРЬ", "ДЕКАБРЬ"};
        
        int[] days = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        
        String[] weeks = {"Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"};
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите год: ");
        int year = in.nextInt();
        
        // Вычисление дня недели для 1 января
        int week = (year + (year - 1) / 4 + 6) % 7;
        
        // Подгон февраля под високосный год
        if (year % 4 != 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)) {
            days[1] = 28; // Не високосный
        }
        else {
            days[1] = 29; // Високосный
        }
        
        // Вывод месяца
        for (int month = 0; month < months.length; month++) {
            // Месяц
            System.out.println("\n\n      " + months[month]);
            
            // Дни недели
            for (int j = 1; j < weeks.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(weeks[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(weeks[0]);
            
            //Отступ до 1 числа
            for (int j = 0; j < week - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print("   ");
            }
            
            // Вывод чисел
            int day = 1;
            for (; day <= days[month]; day++) {
                System.out.print(day + " ");
                if (day < 10) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                week++;
                if (week == 7) {
                    week = 0;
                } else if (week == 1) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```